# Error on 'If condition'-the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

in data frame ad2, if cost values is between upper & lower, then make a new data frame.
I tried the following:

```
if (ad2$Cost.x>=ad2$lower & ad2$Cost.x<=ad2$upper) {
  ad3<-ad2[ad2$Country,ad2$Brand, ad2$Year, ad2$BU219.x, ad2$Cost.x, ad2$Value.x, ad2$Optimized_point.x]
}
```

but this error comes up

```
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: If your goal is to create a new `data.frame` containing rows where the cost values is between upper & lower, you may want to try `ind <- which(ad2$Cost.x>=ad2$lower & ad2$Cost.x<=ad2$upper); ad3 <- ad2[ind, ]`

Comment: no need to use which in that case, ad3 <- ad2[ad2$Cost.x>=ad2$lower & ad2$Cost.x<=ad2$upper, ] would do.

Answer (score 0):

If you print the values of `ad2$Cost.x>=ad2$lower & ad2$Cost.x<=ad2$upper`, u can see more than one boolean conditions as a result. This is becuase in R all operations are vectorised.

Example:

```
> cc =c(T,F)
> if (cc) print(cc)
[1]  TRUE FALSE
Warning message:
In if (cc) print(cc) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

So use all or any function like this  :

```
> if (all(cc)) print(cc) #If all conditions are true
> if (any(cc)) print(cc)
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

if (ad2$Cost.x>=ad2$lower & ad2$Cost.x<=ad2$upper) {
ad3 <- ad2[ , c(Country,Brand, Year, BU219.x, Cost.x, Value.x, Optimized_point.x)]
}

Comment: You are indexing the columns correctly, but the error as mentioned in the question will come up.